# How to register a .cn domain

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains, whois

I would like to register a `.cn` domain. I found the below pages which list the officially accredited registrars:
-based in China: http://www.cnnic.net.cn/html/Dir/2007/06/05/4635.htm
-based outside China: http://www.cnnic.net.cn/html/Dir/2007/06/25/4671.htm

Needless to say that the registrars based in China have their website in Chinese which effectively prevents me from using them. There are `11` oversea registrars and I'm wondering which one I should be using.

If you look at the big names, they all have their `.cn` registered (`facebook.cn`, `microsoft.cn`...), and whois only shows a `Sponsering registrar` which doesn't seem to be offering domains registration services directly to consumers:

```
$ whois facebook.cn
Domain Name: facebook.cn
ROID: 20050304s10001s04039518-cn
Domain Status: ok
Registrant ID: tuv3ldreit6px8c7
Registrant Organization: Facebook Inc.
Registrant Name: Facebook, Inc.
Registrant Email: admin@lovellsnames.info
Sponsoring Registrar: Tucows, Inc.
```

http://www.tucowsdomains.com/ only seems to offer domain-related help but not registration.

```
$ whois microsoft.cn
Domain Name: microsoft.cn
ROID: 20030312s10001s00043473-cn
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
Registrant ID: mmr-44297
Registrant Organization: Microsoft Corporation
Registrant Name: Domain Administrator
Registrant Email: domains@microsoft.com
Sponsoring Registrar: MarkMonitor, Inc.
```

https://www.markmonitor.com/ seems to offer registration but only to "big" customers, and definitely not to consumers like me via a web portal.

**Q: How do big companies register their `.cn` domains? How consumers like us should do it?**

Answer (score 2):

Here are some registrars to get your .CN domain

http://www.marcaria.com/domains/China/china-domain-registration-cn.asp

http://www.101domain.com/cn.htm